# How to get all possible binary numbers in a vector

Tags: binaryfiles

I'm looking for a way to generate all possible binary combinations and insert that into a vector of strings.

For example, if I have **n=3**, I would like to create a string of vectors that contains all the possible combinations from ["000", ..., "111"].

I have created a code that can generate binary strings of the values.

```
std::vector<std::string> get_combs(std::vector<std::string> vector, const int Z){
  

  //I'm not sure why this line causes the error
  constexpr size_t N = Z;
 

  for(size_t i=0; i<(1<<N); ++i) {
    std::bitset<N> bs = i;
    vec.push_back(bs.to_string());
  }
  
  return vec;
}
  
// Driver Code 
int main() 
{ 
    int Z = 2; 
    std::vector<std::string> values;
    values = get_combs(values, const int Z);
}
```

But right now it's just printing as  0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1

Comment: `int arr[n]` is not standard c++, its a vla, compiler extension. Better use `std::vector`, you already  included `<vector>` but you arent using it.

Comment: Don't use c-style arrays, stick to `std::string`s and `std;;vector`s.

Comment: [`std::next_permutation`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) could be a good start

Comment: @BigBasherSucks Same way you do it now, but instead of printing the result, you can `push_back` the string to the fvalues vector.

Comment: Loop from 0 to `1 << n-1`. Convert each number to a string of binary digits.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: OP want cartesian product, not permutation.

Comment: @Jarod42 Aha ... sloppy reading on my part

Comment: Do you need to do this recursively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is N known at compile-time? If so `std::bitset<N>` could be useful:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    constexpr size_t N = 3;

    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    for (size_t i=0; i<(1<<N); ++i) {
        std::bitset<N> bs = i;
        vec.push_back(bs.to_string());
    }

    // Prints "000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111"
    for (auto& elem: vec) cout << elem << ' ';
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/WxWz43

Comment: Edited, just change N

Comment: N is a template argument to bitset, so it must be know at compile-time (hence the `constexpr`). That's why I asked.

Comment: If N needs to be a runtime value, probably check @molbdnilo 's solution instead.

Answer (score 1):

A non-recursive converting version (loop over all the numbers and convert them to strings of binary digits):

```
std::string to_binstring(int x, int width)
{
    std::string s(width, '0');
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        s[i] = '0' + x % 2;
        x /= 2;
    }
    std::reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
    return s;
}

std::vector<std::string> all_binstrings(int width)
{
    const unsigned int limit = 1 << width;
    std::vector<std::string> bins;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
    {
        bins.push_back(to_binstring(i, width));
    }
    return bins;
}
```

A recursive string-building version (attach '0' and '1' to all of the shorter strings):

```
std::vector<std::string> recursive_binstrings(int width)
{
    if (width == 1)
    {
        return {"0", "1"};
    }
    std::vector<std::string> rest = recursive_binstrings(width-1);
    std::vector<std::string> appended;
    for (const auto& s: rest)
    {
        appended.push_back(s + '0');
        appended.push_back(s + '1');
    }
    return appended;
}
```